# Is it harmful if I try to load a bunch of 404'd links?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, http-status-code-404

I'm developing an image rotation plugin for a company website. The thing is, I want the image replacement process to be as easy and straightforward as possible, so I've set up a bunch of literal strings that my asynchronous loading process will try to load in order to show the images.

Just so you get the idea, the images will be stored in a banner folder, where users can store the images:

```
img1.jpg
img2.png
img3.jpg
img4.jpg
img5.png
```

So my JS will loop 10 times calling a $.ajax that will try to access the images (img1 -  img10) first as a png and then as a jpg.

```
for(var i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/banner/img' + i + '.png',
        ...
        success: ... 
        error: function () {
            $.ajax({url:'/banner/img' + i + '.jpg', ... });
        } 
    });
}
```

This will, of course, generate a whole bunch of 404s. Is there a downside to this method (besides, of course, the 404's it will return)? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No more harmful than loading these images dynamically in the first place... just a waste of some bandwidth.  Why are you doing this though?  The question doesn't make any sense.  And, why are you using two different image formats even though you've only rotated the image?

Comment: The idea is to save time and resources, since the company's policy on changes makes change execution slow and tedious. This way the corporate image user can directly update the banner's content himself, without going through the hassle of requesting a change to the development department.

Comment: What does the file name have to do with absolutely any of that?

Comment: The user can replace the images or change the amount of images rotating in the banner at will.

Comment: Why not load the correct image in the first place?  What does the user replacing images or rotating have anything to do with the file name?

Comment: Because I (the front-end code) have no way of knowing how many images there currently are in the folder, or the format in which they were uploaded. I'm avoiding having to update the page's code every time the images change in the banner.

Comment: You should have some sort of dynamic data source telling your client side code what the images are.  I wouldn't stick to naming them sequentially either...  You will probably want to enable caching of those images indefinitely and if you re-use an existing file name (sequence number) then you won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Brad said, other than wasting bandwidth, pretty much nothing i can think of. But i believe you are trying to detect whether a .png format is given and if its not available, go for the jpg one. You can save some bandwidth using 'type:head' instead in $.ajax as show below,

```js
for(var i = 1; i<= 10; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/banner/img' + i + '.png',
        type:'HEAD',
        error:
            function(){
                $.ajax({url:'/banner/img' + i + '.png', ... });
            },
        success:
            function(){
               $.ajax({url:'/banner/img' + i + '.jpg', ... });
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Great! I updated my code to match this suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: anytime @Niche problem! Glad it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not harmful, but definitely not preferred. Assuming you have access to PHP, I would use separate counters for jpg and png filenames, so you have both `1.jpg` and `1.png` being different images, and then use a directory iterator to get the total number of png and jpg files whenever the website is loaded.

Depending on how much work you want to spend getting php-generated data into the javascript, the cheap fix is inserting `<script>var nJPG=4; var nPNG=2;</script>` somewhere before your javascript in the html.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's some static pages in the way (I know... It sucks), so I can not do any server side checks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't run server side code, you can still use tripflag's suggestion of having a separate list for each supported image type.  This way you only get one 404 for each supported image type, instead of a 404 for every image you guess wrong.